# Converting CSV to nested JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have a CSV file which needs to be converted into a Javascript object / JSON file. Doesn't really matter which since I'll be be handling the data in JS anyway and either is fine.

So for instance this:

```
name,birthday/day,birthday/month,birthday/year,house/type,house/address/street,house/address/city,house/address/state,house/occupants
Lily Haywood,27,3,1995,Igloo,768 Pocket Walk,Honolulu,HI,7
Stan Marsh,19,10,1987,Treehouse,2001 Bonanza Street,South Park,CO,2
```

should become this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Lily Haywood",
        "birthday": {
            "day": 27,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 1995
        },
        "house": {
            "type": "Igloo",
            "address": {
                "street": "768 Pocket Walk",
                "city": "Honolulu",
                "state": "HI"
            },
            "occupants": 7
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Stan Marsh",
        "birthday": {
            "day": 19,
            "month": 10,
            "year": 1987
        },
        "house": {
            "type": "Treehouse",
            "address": {
                "street": "2001 Bonanza Street",
                "city": "South Park",
                "state": "CO"
            },
            "occupants": 2
        }
    }
]
```

This is what I have came up with:

```
function parse(csv){
    function createEntry(header){
        return function (record){
            let keys = header.split(",");
            let values = record.split(",");
            if (values.length !== keys.length){
                console.error("Invalid CSV file");
                return;
            }
            for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
                let key = keys[i].split("/");
                let value = values[i] || null;
                /////
                if (key.length === 1){
                    this[key] = value;
                }
                else {
                    let newKey = key.shift();
                    this[newKey] = this[newKey] || {};
                    //this[newKey][key[0]] = value;
                    if (key.length === 1){
                        this[newKey][key[0]] = value;
                    }
                    else {
                        let newKey2 = key.shift();
                        this[newKey][newKey2] = this[newKey][newKey2] || {};
                        this[newKey][newKey2][key[0]] = value;
                        //if (key.length === 1){}
                        //...
                    }
                }
                /////
                }
        };
    }
    let lines = csv.split("\n");
    let Entry = createEntry(lines.shift());
    let output = [];
    for (let line of lines){
        entry = new Entry(line);
        output.push(entry);
    }
    return output;
}
```

My code works, however there is an obvious flaw to it: for each layer it goes down into (e.g. `house/address/street`), I have to manually write repeated `if / else` statements.

Is there a better way to write it? I know this involves recursion or iteration of some kind but I just can't seem to figure out how.

I've searched around SO but most questions seem to be on doing it in Python instead of JS.

As far as possible I wish to have this done in vanilla JS without any other libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the intended results by creating the Object recursively.
Look at the code below:

```js
var csv = [
  "name,birthday/day,birthday/month,birthday/year,house/type,house/address/street,house/address/city,house/address/state,house/occupants",
  "Lily Haywood,27,3,1995,Igloo,768 Pocket Walk,Honolulu,HI,7",
  "Stan Marsh,19,10,1987,Treehouse,2001 Bonanza Street,South Park,CO,2"
];

var attrs = csv.splice(0,1);

var result = csv.map(function(row) {
  var obj = {};
  var rowData = row.split(',');
  attrs[0].split(',').forEach(function(val, idx) {
    obj = constructObj(val, obj, rowData[idx]);
  });
  return obj;
})


function constructObj(str, parentObj, data) {
  if(str.split('/').length === 1) {
    parentObj[str] = data;
    return parentObj;
  }

  var curKey = str.split('/')[0];
  if(!parentObj[curKey])
    parentObj[curKey] = {};
  parentObj[curKey] = constructObj(str.split('/').slice(1).join('/'), parentObj[curKey], data);
  return parentObj;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height: 100% !important; top:0}
```

`constructObj()` function basically constructs the resultant object recursively by looking at the column name, so if the column name contains the `/` like in `house/address/street` it will create a key in the object by the name `house` and then recursively calls itself for the rest of the remaining keys in string i.e. `address/street/`. The recursion ends when no more `/` are left in the string and then it simply assigns the value in that key and returns the result object.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Slightly off-topic, why `attrs[0].split(',')` instead of `attrs.split(',')`? Isn't `attrs` just `"name,birthday/day,..."`?

Comment: @rapinopo `.splice()` returns an array of deleted elements. Therefore `attrs` will be an array.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia - this recursive function apparently creates only JSON objects. For instance, I expect house/0/type to create a JSON array by name house with the first JSON Object inside that containing a key called type. It is not working that way.

Answer (score -1):

You can map over your records and create the objects on the fly :

```js
let records = ['Lily Haywood,27,3,1995,Igloo,768 Pocket Walk,Honolulu,HI,7',
'Stan Marsh,19,10,1987,Treehouse,2001 Bonanza Street,South Park,CO,2']

let output = records.map( record => {
 
 let arr = record.split(',')
 
 return {
   "name": arr[0],
        "birthday": {
            "day": parseInt(arr[1]),
            "month": parseInt(arr[2]),
            "year": parseInt(arr[3])
        },
        "house": {
            "type": arr[4],
            "address": {
                "street": arr[5],
                "city": arr[6],
                "state": arr[7]
            },
            "occupants": parseInt(arr[8])
        }
  
 }
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This works as well but doesn't solve the problem; it still requires manually listing out each key.

Comment: Well yes, you do this once, and then if you have a CSV with 500 lines, it creates an array of 500 objects. Where's the problem?